# Laravel 8.4 API GET Routes returning 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hi im working in a shcool project that i have to develop a mysql API. For that i have chosen Laravel 8.4. In my api.php i defined all the routes and for some reason all my get routes that dont require a argument return 404 except the index routes in the resources, that only started happening some time ago.
My api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ComparticipacaoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HoraComparticipacaoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HoraController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PremioComparticipacaoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PremioController;
use App\Models\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|

*/

Route::get('totalabc',function (){
    return response(1);
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::resource('docente', DocenteController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store','show','update','destroy'
]);

Route::resource('categoria', CategoriaController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

Route::resource('hora', HoraController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

Route::resource('comparticipacao', ComparticipacaoController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

Route::resource('premio', PremioController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

Route::resource('horacomparticipacao', HoraComparticipacaoController::class)->only([
    'store', 'index'
]);


Route::post('horacomparticipacao/update', [HoraComparticipacaoController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('horacomparticipacao/delete/{idComparticipacao}/{idhora}', [HoraComparticipacaoController::class, 'destroy']);

Route::resource('premiocomparticipacao', PremioComparticipacaoController::class)->only([
    'store', 'index'
]);
Route::post('premiocomparticipacao/update', [PremioComparticipacaoController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('premiocomparticipacao/delete/{idComparticipacao}/{idPremio}', [PremioComparticipacaoController::class, 'destroy']);


//Horas de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/horas', [DocenteController::class, 'horas'] );

//Premios de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/premios', [DocenteController::class, 'premios']);

//Comparticipações de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/comparticipacoes', [DocenteController::class, 'comparticipacoesDocente']);

//Comparticipacoes aprovadas de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/comparticipacoesaprovadas', [DocenteController::class, 'comparticipacaoesAprovadas']);

//Média de valores atribuídos em premios por docentes em cada ano
Route::get('premio/mediaano/{ano}', [PremioController::class, 'mediaAno']);









//Total Valor Atribúido em premios
//Route::get('premio/totalpremio', [PremioController::class, 'total']);
Route::get('premio/totalpremio', 'PremioController@total');

//Qtd Premios
Route::get('premio/qtd', [PremioController::class, 'qtdPremio']);

//Qtd Comparticipacoes
Route::get('comparticipacao/qtd', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'qtdComparticipacao']);

//Total Valor Comparticipado
Route::get('comparticipacao/total', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'total']);

//Média da percentagem de valor comparticipado
Route::get('comparticipacao/mediacomparticipacao', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'media']);

//Valor de Premios/Horas usadas numa comparticipação
Route::get('comparticipacao/{id}/premioshoras', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'premiosHoras']);

//Comparticipações em que foram gastas Horas
Route::get('comparticipacao/gastohoras', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'gastoHoras']);

//Comparticipações em que foram gastos prémios
Route::get('premio/gastopremios', [PremioComparticipacaoController::class, 'gastoPremios']);
```

The routes that dont work are the ones at the bottom of the file.
I have already tried the `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Do your routes appear in `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: yes they apear https://imgur.com/RPCzz40

Comment: Also note this `Route::get('premio/totalpremio', 'PremioController@total');` is incorrect syntax for Laravel 8.

Comment: Please do not use `->only` and remove `create` and `edit`, simply use `Route::apiResource` and that will automatically exclude this 2 routes... More info on the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#api-resource-routes) and the [official framework GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/277c2fbd0cebd2cb194807654d870f4040e288c0/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L355-L366)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the routes are conflicting with each other. On your `api.php` file you've registered resource routes for `PremioController` -

```
Route::resource('premio', PremioController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);
```

Now once this is registered, any get request to `/premio/anything` will be handled by the show method. So when you're sending a request to `premio/totalpremio` it's being handled by the `show` method instead of the `total` method. The same goes for all the non-functioning `comparticipacao` routes. Updating your `api.php` so that the single get routes come before the resource routes should fix the problem -

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\CategoriaController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ComparticipacaoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HoraComparticipacaoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HoraController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PremioComparticipacaoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PremioController;
use App\Models\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|

*/

Route::get('totalabc',function (){
    return response(1);
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::resource('docente', DocenteController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store','show','update','destroy'
]);

Route::resource('categoria', CategoriaController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

Route::resource('hora', HoraController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

//Qtd Comparticipacoes
Route::get('comparticipacao/qtd', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'qtdComparticipacao']);

//Total Valor Comparticipado
Route::get('comparticipacao/total', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'total']);

//Média da percentagem de valor comparticipado
Route::get('comparticipacao/mediacomparticipacao', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'media']);

//Valor de Premios/Horas usadas numa comparticipação
Route::get('comparticipacao/{id}/premioshoras', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'premiosHoras']);

//Comparticipações em que foram gastas Horas
Route::get('comparticipacao/gastohoras', [ComparticipacaoController::class, 'gastoHoras']);

Route::resource('comparticipacao', ComparticipacaoController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

//Total Valor Atribúido em premios
//Route::get('premio/totalpremio', [PremioController::class, 'total']);
Route::get('premio/totalpremio', 'PremioController@total');

//Qtd Premios
Route::get('premio/qtd', [PremioController::class, 'qtdPremio']);

//Comparticipações em que foram gastos prémios
Route::get('premio/gastopremios', [PremioComparticipacaoController::class, 'gastoPremios']);

Route::resource('premio', PremioController::class)->only([
    'index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'
]);

Route::resource('horacomparticipacao', HoraComparticipacaoController::class)->only([
    'store', 'index'
]);


Route::post('horacomparticipacao/update', [HoraComparticipacaoController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('horacomparticipacao/delete/{idComparticipacao}/{idhora}', [HoraComparticipacaoController::class, 'destroy']);

Route::resource('premiocomparticipacao', PremioComparticipacaoController::class)->only([
    'store', 'index'
]);
Route::post('premiocomparticipacao/update', [PremioComparticipacaoController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('premiocomparticipacao/delete/{idComparticipacao}/{idPremio}', [PremioComparticipacaoController::class, 'destroy']);


//Horas de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/horas', [DocenteController::class, 'horas'] );

//Premios de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/premios', [DocenteController::class, 'premios']);

//Comparticipações de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/comparticipacoes', [DocenteController::class, 'comparticipacoesDocente']);

//Comparticipacoes aprovadas de um docente
Route::get('docente/{id}/comparticipacoesaprovadas', [DocenteController::class, 'comparticipacaoesAprovadas']);

//Média de valores atribuídos em premios por docentes em cada ano
Route::get('premio/mediaano/{ano}', [PremioController::class, 'mediaAno']);
```

All I did is moved the single routes before the resource routes. This way, the exact get calls should be caught by the single get route registration and the others should be caught by the resource controller.

Again I'm not 100% sure about what's going on here just making guesses based on my previous experiences. Let me know if the answer seems too complicated, I'll try to simplify.